# How to configure apollo server with meteor with the meteor/apollo package?

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to build an app with meteor, apollo/graphql for the first time and the tutorial I'm watching might have outdated versions of apollo. I set up my server as:

```
import { createApolloServer } from "meteor/apollo";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";

const typeDefs = `
type Query {
  hi: String
}
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hi() {
      return "Hello world";
    }
  }
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

createApolloServer({ schema });
```

However I usually get this as an error:
`TypeError: graphqlExpress is not a function`

I know it has to do with the apollo package, but I don't know how to get the migration changes made for apollo 2.0.0 into the meteor/apollo file from the migration doc on apollo's site. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If this error is really a result from migration you should also please refer to this question in the Meteor forums in order to provoke a quality improvement of the docs on migration.